# Reordering columns in large data frame

Tags: r

Passing a long vector of characters to to reorder a data.frame gives me the errors seen below

I tried to order the columns manually by using a long string (7152 char). As a workaround, I tried to save the same string in a text file and read in the text file. None of it worked.

```
df<-all_reps[,c(1,2,827,828,3,4,829,830,5,6,831,832,7,8,833,834,9,10,835,836,11,12,837,838,13,14,839,840,15,16,841,842,17,18,843,844,19,20,845,846,21,22,847,848,23,24,849,850,25,26,851,852,27,28,853,854,29,30,855,856,31,32,857,858,33,34,859,860,35,36,861,862,37,38,863,864,39,40,865,866,41,42,867,868,43,44,869,870,45,46,871,872,47,48,873,874,49,50,875,876,51,52,877,878,53,54,879,880,55,56,881,882,57,58,883,884,59,60,885,886,61,62,887,888,63,64,889,890,65,66,891,892,67,68,893,894,69,70,895,896,71,72,897,898,73,74,899,900,75,76,901,902,77,78,903,904,79,80,905,906,81,82,907,908,83,84,909,910,85,86,911,912,87,88,913,914,89,90,915,916,91,92,917,918,93,94,919,920,95,96,921,922,97,98,923,924,99,100,925,926,101,102,927,928,103,104,929,930,105,106,931,932,107,108,933,934,109,110,935,936,111,112,937,938,113,114,939,940,115,116,941,942,117,118,943,944,119,120,945,946,121,122,947,948,123,124,949,950,125,126,951,952,127,128,953,954,129,130,955,956,131,132,957,958,133,134,959,960,135,136,961,962,137,138,963,964,139,140,965,966,141,142,967,968,143,144,969,970,145,146,971,972,147,148,973,974,149,150,975,976,151,152,977,978,153,154,979,980,155,156,981,982,157,158,983,984,159,160,985,986,161,162,987,988,163,164,989,990,165,166,991,992,167,168,993,994,169,170,995,996,171,172,997,998,173,174,999,1000,175,176,1001,1002,177,178,1003,1004,179,180,1005,1006,181,182,1007,1008,183,184,1009,1010,185,186,1011,1012,187,188,1013,1014,189,190,1015,1016,191,192,1017,1018,193,194,1019,1020,195,196,1021,1022,197,198,1023,1024,199,200,1025,1026,201,202,1027,1028,203,204,1029,1030,205,206,1031,1032,207,208,1033,1034,209,210,1035,1036,211,212,1037,1038,213,214,1039,1040,215,216,1041,1042,217,218,1043,1044,219,220,1045,1046,221,222,1047,1048,223,224,1049,1050,225,226,1051,1052,227,228,1053,1054,229,230,1055,1056,231,232,1057,1058,233,234,1059,1060,235,236,1061,1062,237,238,1063,1064,239,240,1065,1066,241,242,1067,1068,243,244,1069,1070,245,246,1071,1072,247,248,1073,1074,249,250,1075,1076,251,252,1077,1078,253,254,1079,1080,255,256,1081,1082,257,258,1083,1084,259,260,1085,1086,261,262,1087,1088,263,264,1089,1090,265,266,1091,1092,267,268,1093,1094,269,270,1095,1096,271,272,1097,1098,273,274,1099,1100,275,276,1101,1102,277,278,1103,1104,279,280,1105,1106,281,282,1107,1108,283,284,1109,1110,285,286,1111,1112,287,288,1113,1114,289,290,1115,1116,291,292,1117,1118,293,294,1119,1120,295,296,1121,1122,297,298,1123,1124,299,300,1125,1126,301,302,1127,1128,303,304,1129,1130,305,306,1131,1132,307,308,1133,1134,309,310,1135,1136,311,312,1137,1138,313,314,1139,1140,315,316,1141,1142,317,318,1143,1144,319,320,1145,1146,321,322,1147,1148,323,324,1149,1150,325,326,1151,1152,327,328,1153,1154,329,330,1155,1156,331,332,1157,1158,333,334,1159,1160,335,336,1161,1162,337,338,1163,1164,339,340,1165,1166,341,342,1167,1168,343,344,1169,1170,345,346,1171,1172,347,348,1173,1174,349,350,1175,1176,351,352,1177,1178,353,354,1179,1180,355,356,1181,1182,357,358,1183,1184,359,360,1185,1186,361,362,1187,1188,363,364,1189,1190,365,366,1191,1192,367,368,1193,1194,369,370,1195,1196,371,372,1197,1198,373,374,1199,1200,375,376,1201,1202,377,378,1203,1204,379,380,1205,1206,381,382,1207,1208,383,384,1209,1210,385,386,1211,1212,387,388,1213,1214,389,390,1215,1216,391,392,1217,1218,393,394,1219,1220,395,396,1221,1222,397,398,1223,1224,399,400,1225,1226,401,402,1227,1228,403,404,1229,1230,405,406,1231,1232,407,408,1233,1234,409,410,1235,1236,411,412,1237,1238,413,414,1239,1240,415,416,1241,1242,417,418,1243,1244,419,420,1245,1246,421,422,1247,1248,423,424,1249,1250,425,426,1251,1252,427,428,1253,1254,429,430,1255,1256,431,432,1257,1258,433,434,1259,1260,435,436,1261,1262,437,438,1263,1264,439,440,1265,1266,441,442,1267,1268,443,444,1269,1270,445,446,1271,1272,447,448,1273,1274,449,450,1275,1276,451,452,1277,1278,453,454,1279,1280,455,456,1281,1282,457,458,1283,1284,459,460,1285,1286,461,462,1287,1288,463,464,1289,1290,465,466,1291,1292,467,468,1293,1294,469,470,1295,1296,471,472,1297,1298,473,474,1299,1300,475,476,1301,1302,477,478,1303,1304,479,480,1305,1306,481,482,1307,1308,483,484,1309,1310,485,486,1311,1312,487,488,1313,1314,489,490,1315,1316,491,492,1317,1318,493,494,1319,1320,495,496,1321,1322,497,498,1323,1324,499,500,1325,1326,501,502,1327,1328,503,504,1329,1330,505,506,1331,1332,507,508,1333,1334,509,510,1335,1336,511,512,1337,1338,513,514,1339,1340,515,516,1341,1342,517,518,1343,1344,519,520,1345,1346,521,522,1347,1348,523,524,1349,1350,525,526,1351,1352,527,528,1353,1354,529,530,1355,1356,531,532,1357,1358,533,534,1359,1360,535,536,1361,1362,537,538,1363,1364,539,540,1365,1366,541,542,1367,1368,543,544,1369,1370,545,546,1371,1372,547,548,1373,1374,549,550,1375,1376,551,552,1377,1378,553,554,1379,1380,555,556,1381,1382,557,558,1383,1384,559,560,1385,1386,561,562,1387,1388,563,564,1389,1390,565,566,1391,1392,567,568,1393,1394,569,570,1395,1396,571,572,1397,1398,573,574,1399,1400,575,576,1401,1402,577,578,1403,1404,579,580,1405,1406,581,582,1407,1408,583,584,1409,1410,585,586,1411,1412,587,588,1413,1414,589,590,1415,1416,591,592,1417,1418,593,594,1419,1420,595,596,1421,1422,597,598,1423,1424,599,600,1425,1426,601,602,1427,1428,603,604,1429,1430,605,606,1431,1432,607,608,1433,1434,609,610,1435,1436,611,612,1437,1438,613,614,1439,1440,615,616,1441,1442,617,618,1443,1444,619,620,1445,1446,621,622,1447,1448,623,624,1449,1450,625,626,1451,1452,627,628,1453,1454,629,630,1455,1456,631,632,1457,1458,633,634,1459,1460,635,636,1461,1462,637,638,1463,1464,639,640,1465,1466,641,642,1467,1468,643,644,1469,1470,645,646,1471,1472,647,648,1473,1474,649,650,1475,1476,651,652,1477,1478,653,654,1479,1480,655,656,1481,1482,657,658,1483,1484,659,660,1485,1486,661,662,1487,1488,663,664,1489,1490,665,666,1491,1492,667,668,1493,1494,669,670,1495,1496,671,672,1497,1498,673,674,1499,1500,675,676,1501,1502,677,678,1503,1504,679,680,1505,1506,681,682,1507,1508,683,684,1509,1510,685,686,1511,1512,687,688,1513,1514,689,690,1515,1516,691,692,1517,1518,693,694,1519,1520,695,696,1521,1522,697,698,1523,1524,699,700,1525,1526,701,702,1527,1528,703,704,1529,1530,705,706,1531,1532,707,708,1533,1534,709,710,1535,1536,711,712,1537,1538,713,714,1539,1540,715,716,1541,1542,717,718,1543,1544,719,720,1545,1546,721,722,1547,1548,723,724,1549,1550,725,726,1551,1552,727,728,1553,1554,729,730,1555,1556,731,732,1557,1558,733,734,1559,1560,735,736,1561,1562,737,738,1563,1564,739,740,1565,1566,741,742,1567,1568,743,744,1569,1570,745,746,1571,1572,747,748,1573,1574,749,750,1575,1576,751,752,1577,1578,753,754,1579,1580,755,756,1581,1582,757,758,1583,1584,759,760,1585,1586,761,762,1587,1588,763,764,1589,1590,765,766,1591,1592,767,768,1593,1594,769,770,1595,1596,771,772,1597,1598,773,774,1599,1600,775,776,1601,1602,777,778,1603,1604,779,780,1605,1606,781,782,1607,1608,783,784,1609,1610,785,786,1611,1612,787,788,1613,1614,789,790,1615,1616,791,792,1617,1618,793,794,1619,1620,795,796,1621,1622,797,798,1623,1624,799,800,1625,1626,801,802,1627,1628,803,804,1629,1630,805,806,1631,1632,807,808,1633,1634,809,810,1635,1636,811,812,1637,1638,813,814,1639,1640,815,816,1641,1642,817,818,1643,1644,819,820,1645,1646,821,822,1647,1648,823,824,1649,1650,825,826,1651,1652)]
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>   "282,457,458,1283,1284,459,460,1285,1286,461,462,1287,1288,463,464,1289,1290,465,466,1291,1292,467,468,1293,1294,469,470,1295,1296,471,472,1297,1298,473,474,1299,1300,475,476,1301,1302,477,478,

```
test<-read.table('order.txt',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test<-as.character(test)
df<-all_reps[,c(test)]
```

> Error in all_reps[, c(test)] : subscript out of bounds

Is the problem that the column vector consists of 7152 chars?

Comment: I think instead of `read.table` use `test <- scan('order.txt', sep=",", quiet = TRUE)`  It is not clear how the data is stored in the 'order.txt'  With `read.table`, it can either be 7152 columns  or something else and `as.character` works only on vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better option would be to `scan` and use that in rearrangng the columns

```
test <- scan('order.txt', sep=",", quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: perfect. amazing... changing to scan and it works like a charm! Thank you very much! highly appreciated!